# ecdf plot error in ggplot2: unknown color name

Tags: r, ggplot2, ecdf

I get an error with a very simple ecdf plot in ggplot. Error in color name.

```
    library(ggplot2)

ggplot(iris) +
  stat_ecdf(aes(x = Sepal.Length,
                col = Species),
            geom = "point")


Error: Unknown colour name: setosa
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this - your code gives the expected result for me. Try restarting R and rerunning your code

Comment: restarted R. Same error

Comment: Try adding `+ scale_color_manual(values = rainbow(3))`. Does that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sometimes happened to me with no apparent cause, but I solved it just forcing Species to be Factor.

Try this:

```
        library(ggplot2)

ggplot(iris) +
  stat_ecdf(aes(x = Sepal.Length,
                col = as.factor(Species)),
            geom = "point")
```

Answer (score 0):

Setosa is a value of the Species field. It seems the code is interpreting the contents of Species as literal colours for those entries. It seems somewhere in your code or session scale_colour_identity() has been activated.

EDIT:

I ran your code exactly as you provided it and it runs fine and produces the expected result with the expected behaviour of assigning three default colours to the three species.
So the problem is definitely in something that you did not include in your post.